# WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION, Wifi Direct, Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect two P2p devices using `Wifi-direct` in Android. I made sure that i have all the `permissions` needed and `Broadcast Receiver` is registered. But still i am not listening to the `WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION` action. Please suggest me to overcome this problem or suggest me other solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As show in the documentation[1] you could implement the connection in this way.

```
 public void connect() {

    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = "DEVICE_TO_CONNECT_MAC_ADDRESS";
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;

    mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

After that, modifie the BroadcastReceiver in order to request for connection info using an instance of WifiP2pManager as in

```
if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

    if (mManager == null) {
         return;
    }
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
               .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
         // We are connected with the other device, request connection
         // info to find group owner IP

         mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, connectionListener);
    }
}
```

This block should be implemented on a BrodacastReceiver that listens to WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION intent.

Now, implement the interface WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener[2].

```
@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {

    // InetAddress from WifiP2pInfo struct.
    InetAddress groupOwnerAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());

    // After the group negotiation, we can determine the group owner.
    if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
        // Do whatever tasks are specific to the group owner.
        // One common case is creating a server thread and accepting
        // incoming connections.
    } else if (info.groupFormed) {
        // The other device acts as the client. In this case,
        // you'll want to create a client thread that connects to the group
        // owner.
    }
}
```

Hope this help. :)

[1] - http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#connect

[2] - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener.html